# _Who_ has which privileges?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

When I click on the arrow next to my name, one of the items on the menu is "privileges", and when I click on that I see this:

trusted user 22%
protect questions 30%
access to moderator tools 45%
approve tag wiki edits 90%
cast close and reopen votes 100%

etc.

So I wonder: How can I see a list of the trusted users, a list of those who can protect questions, and list of those with access to moderator tools, etc?

Also, is there a list of all users in order of reputation from highest to lowest?  And if I simply want to know *how many* people (not necessarily which ones) have reputations in a specified range, how would I get that?

Answer (score 5):

Click the [users](https://math.stackexchange.com/users) link that is on every page of the main site. Select the tab to sort by reputation, and select the time-frame to be all. That shows you all the users with reputations sorted from highest to lowest.

Since privileges are linked to rep, this is also how you determine who has what privileges.

On the [reputation league site](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/alltime/math) (which is accessible from the bottom of the "list of users" page), there is a table with the statistics of total reputation on this site.

At the current moment there are:

- 2 users with 50,000+
- 4 users with 25,000+ (by this it is meant 25,000+ and 50,000-)
- 24 with 10,000+
- 25 with 5000+
- 47 with 3000+
- 46 with 2000+
- 112 with 1000+
- 231 with 500+
- 526 with 200+

This roughly corresponds with the more major reputation milestones for earning privileges. (For example, 3K is the threashold for voting to close/reopen, and 10K is the threshold for Moderator Tools.)

**Edit**: As there seems to have been some confusion in the comments, the line in the above table "by this it is meant 25,000+ and 50,000-" is to apply, mutatis mutandis, to each of the lines below. So the total number of 200+ rep members is 526 + 231 + 112 + 46 + 47 + 25 + 24 + 4 + 2  = 1017 people.

Comment: [As a direct link...](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)

Comment: Also: Moderators.

Comment: Even with what you suggest, it does not seem easy to find out how many users have reputations in the interval $[100,300]$.  That's not important if what you want is to find out who has access to moderator tools or the like, but one might still be curious.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Michael Yes. You'd need to learn abit about how to run database queries. Data.SE exists for this purpose. You can do something like [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1657/askubuntu-user-counts-by-reputation-and-privileges) (presumably you can modify that query a tiny bit to make it run on Maths).

Comment: @J.M. teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: @J.M., Willie: Kill a man, and you have bait for the next fishing trip.

Comment: @Willie: it makes more sense to give users with 20k+ reputation.

Comment: Those numbers imply that we have only between 231 - 526 *active* members. Is it really that low? Perhaps there are many more active members with rep below  200 who are merely lurkers? Is there any way to see that with mod tools?

Comment: @Asaf: I didn't determine the algorithm. And I wrote "roughly".

Comment: Willie: A quick calculation: 4 in a row, 7 rows + 2 users whose reputation is 10k+ all in all 30 users who can use the moderator tools.

Comment: @Asaf: I've no idea what you just wrote.

Comment: There are exactly **30** users (for now) whose reputation is over 10k points.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Thus we have roughly 500 - 1000 "active" members, i.e. with rep 200+ - 500+